# How to create an extra field in the profile module to only accept the numeric values?

Tags: 6, entities, users

I am creating extra fields in the user registration form. for this I am using the profile module.

In this module there is no option form creating a text field which should only accept the numeric values just like in drupal 7.

So how will I create such field in the user registration form?

Any idea?

Comment: There's a number field module. If you can't find it, I can take a look, but search and you should get it.

Comment: there is no such module I found. We can create the numeric fields in the cck fields but can't create in the user profile to appear in the user registration form.

Comment: The answerer below has the number field I was talking about. It's a part of CCK and not a standalone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a custom numeric validation to profile form using form alter. First Add single line text box to profile form then with form alter define custom validation function.

```
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'profile_form_profile') {
      $form['#validate'][]='numeric_validation';
  }
}


function numeric_validation($form_state){
   //the form state variable will contain your text box value,
   //do your custom validation
   //if not numeric add error
      form_set_error("validate",'You must enter numeric value');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Install [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) module. Enable the **number** module that comes with CCK module. Once you enable the module you can able to add integer field to the Profile Content type if you are using [content_profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module to add fields to registration.

See the screenshow below that i just got to do it using CCK, Number, Content Profile module in Drupal 6.

[image]

Comment: This is the number field I was talking about. I forgot it was a part of CCK.

Comment: I am using the profile module which comes the durpal core. I am not using the content_profile module and did not know how to add fields to the user registration form using the content_profile.

Comment: If you are using the profile module which comes the durpal core, the below answer will work